# AsynchronousDispatcher error

Tags: java, jax-rs, jboss7.x

i am getting the error when i try to upload a file based exactly off the example shown here
[Sample](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/)

The error is

> Allocate exception for servlet com.testapp.rest.JaxRsActivator: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a public constructor for class org.jboss.resteasy.core.AsynchronousDispatcher

What can this mean?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If deploying to JBoss 7.x you need to change the scope of your resteasy dependencies to `provided`. This is because those particular libraries are already included in JBoss as modules:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.GA</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: To those coming here, also ensure that you check which versions of the libraries are already/actually deployed JBOSS - e.g your POM might be pointing to 2.2.0.GA, yet the server has 3.0.10.Final (as in my case), and this caused me so much headache!

Comment: What if I want a custom dependency of resteasy to be able to use it with different containers? am I stuck with the provided version? Seriously?

Comment: not worked! Changed stope, than update maven, clean, install, built but no luck

Comment: @Perception Can you elaborate what do you mean by `change the scope of your resteasy dependencies to provided`? I am using WildFly 10 on my eclipse and have dependency with this version `<version>2.2.1.GA</version>` defined in my `pom.xml`

Answer (score 4):

I was using **wildfly 10** to deploy my application when I got this error and tried the above solutions and didn't work for me and finally I had to exclude the jar `resteasy-jaxrs` using maven exclusions

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: On wildfly 10 it works for me https://stuetzpunkt.wordpress.com/2017/02/23/upload-an-image-to-wildfly-resteasy/

Answer (score 2):

Like a charm

One more thing, make sure you check for resteasy

```
$ mvn dependency:tree | grep "resteasy"

[INFO] \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0.10.Final:provided
[INFO]    +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:3.0.10.Final:provided
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's worth to mention that the RESTeasy documentation has [information](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.6.Final/userguide/html_single/#Installation_Configuration) on how to upgrade the RESTeasy included in JBoss, which as mentioned above can cause some headache if you try to use another version.